# Progressbar on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation, drawer

I want to put a progressbar on action bar, but i have a navigation drawer, How can i do that?

Seems like the image:

[image]

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is an impact with navigation drawer or not, but to add the progress dialog in the action bar, you can do that : in your `onCreate()`, add this before calling `setContentView()` :
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);`

Then before you want your progress bar to show up, add :
`setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);`

And then set it to false to hide it.

I hope that will help you !